# Evaling files in directory

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

Is there any way to get python-mode to eval all files in a directory (or at least all the files I'm importing from)?

When I work on a file that imports from another file in the same directory, I have to kill and then re-create the inferior python process in order to pick up changes made in the dependent files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun eval-all-the-python ()
  (interactive)
  (mapcar #'python-shell-send-file
          (cl-remove-if-not
           (lambda(x)(string-match "py$" x))
           (directory-files default-directory))))
```

Just paste this in `*scratch*` and <kbd>C-j</kbd> after both expressions.
<kbd>M-x eval-all-the-python</kbd> when visiting one of the python files.
Make sure to test this with `emacs -q`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. I'm relatively new to python and python-mode, but I feel like it's something to do with the compilation. Even if I eval and shell-send-file each buffer manually, I'm still not picking up changes. Its like the Inferior Python process is using old .pyc files and not re-compiling anything.

Comment: Test again with `emacs -q`

Answer (score -1):

Make a script that reads the directory and evaluates the files in it. Run that.